# Does pdb has the layout src like gdb?

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, pdb, gdb-python

In `gdb`, we can use `layout src` to get a pretty good debug text-UI.
Does pdb(The Python Debugger) have something equivalent? In `pdb`, I can only see the next line that is going to be executed, which is annoying.

`gdb text ui` is shown below:

[image: gdb text-ui]

Answer (score 5):

> Does pdb(The Python Debugger) have something equivalent?

No, but you can use [pudb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) which is more close to `layout src` in gdb. From [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools) about pudb:

> A visual, console-based, full-screen debugger, designed as a more
>   comfortable drop-in replacement for pdb. (also supports IPython)